# Swift conversion of NSColor.textColor to cgColor ignores theme

Tags: swift, xcode, macos

Since macOS Big Sur the system's menu bar has different content colors depending on the wallpaper (not depending on dark/light mode anymore). In general it's easy to use that color, as `NSColor.textColor` is the currently used text color. However, when using a background color this needs to be converted to CGColor, which seems to be not supporting this "live updating".

I tried the following:

```swift
let contentColor = NSColor.textColor // black/white at this point
contentColor.cgColor // always white at his point
```

How is it possible to convert the actually computed NSColor to the CGColor?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`CGColor` and `CALayer` don’t understand dynamic color as it is in AppKit and UIKit concept. You need to handle that manually. So this will have two phases:

#### Detect the change

Observe for changes somewhere

```
DistributedNotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(interfaceModeChanged(notification:)), name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "AppleInterfaceThemeChangedNotification"), object: nil)
```

#### Apply the change

```
@objc func interfaceModeChanged(notification: NSNotification) {
    switch view.effectiveAppearance.name {
    case .darkAqua: print("Set a Dark Color")
    default: print("Handle other states here")
    }
}
```

Note that there are lots of `NSAppearance.Name`s in the AppKit. So you may want to make sure to handle all cases properly.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! In general this is working fine, but seems to be only considering the system theme/mode but not of the menu bar. When changing the wallpaper and the menu bar appearance changes the view.effectiveAppearance is still the same.

Comment: Maybe you should search for **detecting** your desired change and do the **apply** section there

Comment: I managed to fix it, the problem was that I used the effective appearance of the view instead of the status item's button. With the latter it's working fine and switching between "NSAppearanceNameVibrantDark" and "NSAppearanceNameVibrantLight" depending on the wallpaper.

Comment: and `statusItem.addObserver(self, forKeyPath: "button.effectiveAppearance", options: NSKeyValueObservingOptions.new, context: nil)` for detecting the wallpaper change

Answer (score 0):

I create a 1x1 NSView, set the appearance, draw fill view, generate a Bitmap and read de pixel.

https://github.com/frang75/nappgui_src/blob/main/src/osgui/osx/oscolor.m